# Amazon Fling iOS SDK issue when streaming a video

Tags: amazon-fire-tv, fling

I am integrating the Amazon Fling SDK into my iOS app and faced the issue. When casting a video, playback on Fire TV stops immediately or after several seconds and a white video frame is displayed on TV.
The SDK reports the error with the ErrorContent condition.

I am experiencing the same issue with other third-party iOS apps that utilise the Fling SDK (Tubio, Screen Mirror).

Is it a known bug?